# WordPress PHP changes are not reflected

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

Whenever I change code from WordPress admin theme editor, changes are not reflected on website although changes are directly happening in back end theme customize page `/client-area/wp-admin/customize.php`.

Following this link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changes-not-reflected, I dont have WP-cache plugin installed in word press. CSS changes are happening. I have tried adding this line in config.php `define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);` and clearing browser cache.

Edit :

I have two plugins installed `CataBlog and word press importer`

Comment: what kind of changes?

Comment: In menu if I change about us to some other text nothing happens on web site, but i can see change on back end theme customize page.

Comment: Try to reload the page with ctrl+f5

Comment: I am on firefox tried ctrl+f5 and ctrl+shift+R.